# VBoxManage gives error importing appliance

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I was following along in a RHCSA labs course and ran into the following error I can not seem to get past. I know someone else who successfully ran through the installation so I am curious what is going wrong for me.

Below I have my environment information and the steps I followed to recreate the error on my second machine.

My Environment Info:

| OS: | Ubuntu 22.04 | Windows 10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vagrant: | 2.3.0 | 2.3.2 |
| vboxmanage: | 6.1.38 | 7.1 |

Steps to Reproduce:

- Install VirtualBox
- Install Vagrant

```
git clone https://github.com/rdbreak/rhcsa8env
cd rhcsa8env
vagrant up
```

Should get through setting up "server2" but then "repo" fails with following error.

#### The Error:

```
=========================================================================================
==> repo: Importing base box 'rdbreak/rhel8repo'...
Progress: 90%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
Command: ["import", "/root/.vagrant.d/boxes/rdbreak-VAGRANTSLASH-rhel8repo/1.1/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "Red-Hat-Environments_default_1616276906523_91907_1667201066023_33079", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "/root/VirtualBox VMs/Red-Hat-Environments_default_1616276906523_91907_1667201066023_33079/box-disk001.vmdk"]
Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /root/.vagrant.d/boxes/rdbreak-VAGRANTSLASH-rhel8repo/1.1/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) - Invalid argument value (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 1379 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp

=========================================================================================
```

This error comes when I attempt to import the virtual appliance to virtualbox so I am leaning towards virtualbox being the part having the issue but I have no idea what the issue is.

#### Things I've tried:

1. I tried this on two different machines (Windows & Linux)
2. Tried running `vagrant destroy -f`
3. Removed all boxes with `vagrant box remove <box-name>`
4. Removed vagrant project files (removed .vagrant from project directory)
5. Cleared contents for virtual box (For Linux it was `~/.config/Virtualbox/` For windows it was `~/Library/Virtualbox`)
6. Tried importing the .ova file manually with the virtualbox GUI.

What else can I do to fix this?

I have also read this could be due to not enough room on the disk or in memory but I have over 2 TB of free storage and 37 GB of unused RAM when I am hitting this error so I feel that can't be reason.

Comment: Did you assign enough memory in Virtual Box for the guest machine?  That is independent of the total amount of physical disk.

Comment: For “memory “ read disk space

Comment: Trying to see where I can check this. Would this be something set in the Vagrant file?

Comment: Per VBOV documentation ....   Select a virtual machine in the Virtual Machine Library window and click Settings. In the Settings window, click the hard disk you want to resize. Use the Disk size slider to set the new size.

Comment: Seems to still get the error while importing the VM even if I double the RAM to 4Gigs.

Comment: Did you also provide additional Disk Space?

Comment: Oops just realized you said HD ‍♂️..let me try creating a larger .vmdk

Comment: What happened when provided enough disk space?

Comment: Apologies for the delay on this. I tried creating another virtual disk and then attaching the vdmk and the new virtual disk to a vm but no luck. Not sure what is going on. I had someone else follow the same steps and they do not run into the error which makes me think its something about my machine >.<

Comment: Are you working in a partition that is too small?

Comment: My two cents? The disk attached the VM in VirtualBox may be a large partition, but the volume the VM sees doesn’t use the full space. How to fix this? I forgot. But there is a way to actually expand the volume to take up the full partition space. My advice for this? Login to the VM and do a `df -h` to see actual space available and if something seems amiss that is your issue.